# Promise rejection not handled with try/catch block (Firebase verifyPhoneNumber)

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication

Expected behaviour:

I have implemented `auth().verifyPhoneNumber(phonenumber)`, and I would like to implement error handling by using a try catch block.

Code example:

```
    try {
      await auth().verifyPhoneNumber("+852 90815   ");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.code);
    }
  ;
```

Actual behaviour:

When this code is ran, no console has been registered and promise rejection is raised.

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 19):
Error: [auth/invalid-phone-number] The format of the phone number provided is incorrect.

How do I implement this properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
await auth().verifyPhoneNumber("+852 90815   ").catch((e)=>{
    console.log(e);
});
```

Instead